# jquery equal height plugin adding margin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How would I add to the code below to work out if a DIV has any margin-top/margin-bottom? The situation I have at the moment is that I have 2 columns (DIV's) 1 have a margin-top and the other doesn't which causes the columns not to line up correctly.

Sorry the code has been minified and I have lost the original.

```
$.fn.equalHeight = function (a) {
    var b = {
        delay: 100,
        minusHeight: 0
    };
    var a = $.extend(b, a);
    var c = 0;
    var d = 0;
    var e = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        e.each(function () {
            c = $(this).outerHeight();
            d = c > d ? c : d
        });
        return e.each(function () {
            var b = $(this);
            var c = d - (b.outerHeight() - b.height()) - a.minusHeight;
            var e = jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 7 ? "height" : "min-height";
            b.css(e, c + "px")
        })
    }, a.delay)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `true` as a parameter to [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) so that it includes the margin in the calculations.

But there is another issue with your code.. You **cannot** return anything from a timeout, and you seem to have placed your return code in there..

This means you are breaking the jQuery chaining system..

Your code should probably be

```
$.fn.equalHeight = function(a) {
    var b = {
        delay: 100,
        minusHeight: 0
    };
    var a = $.extend(b, a);
    var c = 0;
    var d = 0;

    this.each(function() {
        c = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        d = c > d ? c : d;
    });
    return this.each(function() {
        var b = $(this);
        var c = d - (b.outerHeight(true) - b.height()) - a.minusHeight;
        var e = (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 7) ? "height" : "min-height";
        setTimeout( function(){
            b.css(e, c + "px");
        }, a.delay);
    });
};
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DXHtk/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the div for margins using the `css()` function of jQuery. Unfortunately shorthand css properties like `margin` aren't supported and you'll have to do it in the form of `css('marginTop')`, `css('marginBottom')` and so on. You can then conditionally modify each `div` so that it will line up.